# Call php function using ajax to query api

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to contact an external API in Wordpress. The idea is that a user presses a button link and a php function is called through ajax that loads the data from the API onto the page.

```
The button: 
<a data-id="5" class="product-cat">Product Category</a>

The ajax function:
    $(document).on( 'click', '.product-cat', function( event ) {
    $product = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxproducts.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_product_load',
            datavar: $product.data( 'data-id' )
        },

        success: function ( result ) {
            alert( result );
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

The problem I am having right now is that nothing is happening when I click on the link. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it's better to attach the click the to product instead the document. Also to get the id you may use $(this).attr('data-id')

Comment: @TemaniAfif You mean `$(this).data('id')` right?

Comment: @Elli Whats the browser console show?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone both are correct ;)

Comment: @Elli Still waiting for you to answer **Whats the browser console show?**

Comment: So this works as it is, however, in my local development nothing is still happening. Nothing is showing in my console. I have enqueued my script correctly I believe, but nothing is showing in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to attach the click event to only the button and also update how you get the data-id, you my do like this :

```js
$(".product-cat").click(function() {
  //to sow the content of data-id
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
  // you may also use 
  console.log($(this).data('id'));
  
  

  /*$.ajax({
      url: ajaxproducts.ajaxurl,
      type: 'post',
      data: {
          action: 'ajax_product_load',
          datavar: $(this).attr('data-id' )
      },

      success: function ( result ) {
          alert( result );
      }
  })*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-id="5" class="product-cat">Product Category</a>
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone updated my answer to show both alternative

Comment: Still not the issue, I'm waiting for the OP to mention a CORS blocking because it seems everyone has missed the first sentence in the question **I am trying to contact an external API**

Comment: yes, but he said "nothing is happening" and when we see that there is only the success implemented, so it means that it fall into errors and am sure it's related to datavar which is incorrect ... maybe it's not the only issue, but it's wrong.

Comment: Appreciate the comments. So this works as it is, however, in my local development nothing is still happening. Nothing is showing in my console. I have enqueued my script correctly I believe, but nothing is showing in the console.

Comment: @Elli can you also add the error part to see if it falls there ?

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.product-cat').click(function() {


$product = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxproducts.ajaxurl,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_product_load',
            datavar: $product.data( 'data-id' )
        },

        success: function ( result ) {
            alert( result );
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: you may take a tour into the site before start answering questions so you understand how to do it well https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer